# How to specify assumptions before evaluation?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, assumptions, complex

If I request mathematica evaluate an integral for me, I'll often get a more general `ConditionalExpression` than I want.   Example :

```
Clear[ii, u, z, l, jj]
ii = Integrate[ 1 / Sqrt[z^2 + u^2], {z, -l, l}]
```

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[ -Log[-l + Sqrt[l^2 + u^2]] + Log[l + Sqrt[l^2 + u^2]], 
>                                        Re[u/l] != 0 || Im[u/l] >= 1 || Im[u/l] <= -1]
> ```

I can reduce this after the fact with something like:

```
jj = FullSimplify[ii, u > 0 && l > 0 && Element[ u | l, Reals] ]
```

> ```
> Log[(u^2 + 2 l (l + Sqrt[l^2 + u^2]))/u^2]
> ```

but I'd imagine it should often simplify the calculations if I could provide the assumptions up front, especially the obvious ones like restricting various variables to the domain of reals.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Integrate` can take the option `Assumptions`.

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[z^2 + u^2], {z, -l, l}, 
  Assumptions -> u > 0 && l > 0 && Element[u | l, Reals]]

 ==> 2 Log[(l + Sqrt[l^2 + u^2])/u]
```

Alternatively use `Assuming`.

```
Assuming[u > 0 && l > 0 && Element[u | l, Reals], 
 Integrate[1/Sqrt[z^2 + u^2], {z, -l, l}]]

==> 2 Log[(l + Sqrt[l^2 + u^2])/u]
```

Answer (score 15):

For   `Integrate` as well as for `Simplify`, `Refine` `FunctionExpand`, `Limit` etc. there is an option [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Assumptions.html?q=Assumptions&lang=en):

```
Integrate[ 1/Sqrt[ z^2 + u^2], {z, -l, l}, Assumptions -> (u | l) ∈ Reals]
```

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[ 2 ArcSinh[ l/Abs[ u]], u != 0 && l >= 0]
> ```

or one can use

```
Assuming[ (u | l) ∈ Reals, Integrate[ 1/Sqrt[ z^2 + u^2], {z, -l, l}]]
```

the latter is more handy for `CompoundExpression`'s, e.g.

```
Assuming[ (u | l) ∈ Reals,
          int = Integrate[1/Sqrt[z^2 + u^2], {z, -l, l}]; Simplify[int, int[[2]]] ]
```

> ```
> 2 ArcSinh[ l/Abs[ u]]
> ```

Another way of making assumptions  is to use `$Assumptions` globally in a `Mathematica` session or to close it in `Block`, e.g.

```
Block[{ $Assumptions = (u | l) ∈ Reals}, 
                                         Integrate[ 1/Sqrt[ z^2 + u^2], {z, -l, l}]]
```

**Edit**

The integral in the question provides a good example for a throughout discussion of assumptions methods like `Assumptions`, `Assuming` or `$Assumptions`.

The OP seems to need the integral in the real domain and if not specified explicitely in general Mathematica evaluates integrals by default in complex numbers.

- `u > 0` and `l > 0`  implies `Element[u | l, Reals]`, thus we need not to add this assumption :

  ```
   Integrate[ 1/Sqrt[ z^2 + u^2], {z, -l, l}, Assumptions -> u > 0 && l > 0]
  ```

  > ```
  > 2 Log[( l + Sqrt[ l^2 + u^2])/u]
  > ```
- `Element[u | l, Reals]` is a more general assumption, and when we use it in `Assuming` or adding such `Assumptions`  in `Integrate` we obtain a slightly more general expression. To see it we write :

  ```
  ComplexExpand[ 2 ArcSinh[ l/Abs[ u]]]
  ```

  > ```
  > 2 I Arg[Sqrt[ 1 + l^2/Abs[ u]^2] + l/Abs[ u]] + Log[(Sqrt[1 + l^2/Abs[u]^2] + l/Abs[u])^2]
  > ```

[image]

then we can impose a stronger assumption, to get what we get using `Assumptions` in `Integrate`  :

```
    Refine[ %, l ∈ Reals && u > 0]
```

> ```
>   2 Log[ Sqrt[ 1 + l^2/u^2] + l/u ]
> ```

We could also get this with `FunctionExpand` using `u > 0` and then passing it to `TrigToExp`:

```
FunctionExpand[ 2 ArcSinh[ l /Abs[ u]], u > 0] // TrigToExp
```

Comment: Good point about the inequalities implicitly assuming Reals +1.

Comment: @AndyRoss Thanks !  Such issues are ubiquitous, making a good CAS is a really hard task.

Comment: Thanks for the mention of $Assumptions.  That looks very handy.

Comment: @Artes Considering your answer, I don't understand why Assuming[x>0,TrueQ[x>0]] does reply False. Could you please explain?

Comment: @max When you evaluate only `TrueQ[x > 0]` outside `Assuming` you get `False` since `TrueQ` may have only logical values and while you haven't assigned any value to `x` it has to return `False`. `Assuming[cond, eqn]` is supposed to work with equations or mathematical functions which return numerical values. Nevertheless when you set e.g. `x=5` then `Assuming[x > 0, TrueQ[x > 0]]` will return `True` unlike e.g. `Assuming[x < 0, TrueQ[x < 0]]` just because `TrueQ` is a logical operator not an equation and `x` has an assigned value.

Comment: @Artes Thank you very much for your answer. As I thought it was a question on its own, I asked it [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3541/796). Thanks a lot.