# Symbolic Definite Integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

How do I perform

```
Integrate[Sin[x]^2/(z^2 + R^2 - 2 zRCos[x])^(3/2), {x, 0, Pi}]
```

where `z` and `R` are constants. I would like if possible the result in terms of `z` and `R`.

Comment: I'd start putting spaces between z, R and Cos in your expression. After that, shift enter and a couple of seconds patience and you should have your result.

Comment: About 7 seconds.

Answer (score 5):

At first, if one is not familiar with *Mathematica* syntax there is so called [Free-Form input](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/NewIn80DynamicInteractivity.html). These blog posts by Stephen Wolfram written when *Mathematica 8*  had been released discuss related issues extensively:

- [The Free-Form Linguistics Revolution in Mathematica](http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/11/15/the-free-form-linguistics-revolution-in-mathematica/)
- [Programming with Natural Language Is Actually Going to Work](http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/11/16/programming-with-natural-language-is-actually-going-to-work/)

In a new cell one uses this shorthand `=` to start free-form input, copying the given  command and evaluating it we get an appropriate form of ordinary `Mathematica` input and a bit later the result  in terms of `ConditionalExpression[ expr, cond]` (`the result == expr` when the condition `cond` is satisfied):

[image]

Alternatively, one can converse free-form linguistics to inline *Mathematica* input ( shorthand `Ctrl + =`)

[image]

Then clicking on the result we get a correct input line.  Now, even a complete beginner should get an idea what should be an appropriate input form,  instead of `*` between symbolic variables one can use spaces as well (see e.g. [Mathematical Typesetting](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/MathematicalTypesetting.html) guide).

When the syntax is not a problem anymore we could enhance our input.

Since we'd like to get a symbolic result it is resonable to add some assumptions (there is an option `Assumptions` in `Integrate` and other important functions in calculus, see a related post [How to specify assumptions before evaluation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/how-to-specify-assumptions-before-evaluation/2406#2406) )  to speed up symbolic processing. In general, (if there are adequate built-in rewrite rules) we can expect the result in terms of `ConditionalExpression`. We can get rid of it with e.g. `Refine[ ConditionalExpression[ expr, cond], cond]`, sometimes we might need `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` instead of `Refine`, for more complete discussion of simplification methods see [What is the difference between a few simplification techniques?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4522/what-is-the-difference-between-a-few-simplification-techniques).

For the problem at hand we add assumptions that parameters `z` and `R` are real to avoid unnecessary and time-consuming symbolic processing, moreover we want to exclude `z == R` or `z == -R` since there would be a singularity in the integrand at `x == 0` and `x == Pi`. For terse coding we could define a new function in terms of elliptic integrals of the first and the second kind:

```
f[z_, R_] = Integrate[ Sin[x]^2/(z^2 + R^2 - 2 z R Cos[x])^(3/2), {x, 0, Pi}, 
                       Assumptions -> z != -R && z != R && (z | R) ∈ Reals && z != 0]
```

> ```
> (-(R + z)^2 EllipticE[(4 R z)/(R + z)^2] + (R^2 + z^2) EllipticK[(4 R z)/(R + z)^2]
>   )/(R^2 z^2 Abs[R + z])
> ```

```
f[z, R] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

We could visualize our symbolic expression:

```
Plot3D[ f[z, R], {R, 0.1, 3}, {z, 0.1, 3}, 
        PlotPoints -> 70, MaxRecursion -> 3, Exclusions -> z == R]
```

[image]

or with `ContourPlot`:

```
ContourPlot[ f[z, R], {R, 0, 3}, {z, 0, 3}, 
             PlotPoints -> 60, MaxRecursion -> 3, Contours -> 17, 
             ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"]
```

[image]