# Finding integral bounds

Tags: equation-solving, integral-equations, calculus-and-analysis

i have this integral shown below is equal to 1, and i need to find "a" on mathematica, but I'm not sure how.

integral (from 0 to a) sqrt((-50.8938 sin(8.4823 t))^2+(4-11.3097 sin(11.3097 t))^2) dt = 1

any suggestions?

Comment: If you  are asking a question about _Mathematica_ why don't you write your code in a _Mathematica_-friendly way?

Comment: Start with the free-form input, see closely related: [Symbolic Definite Integration](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28413/symbolic-definite-integration/28417#28417)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f[t_?NumericQ] = 
  Sqrt[(-50.8938 Sin[8.4823 t])^2 + (4 - 11.3097 Sin[11.3097 t])^2];
```

Looking at a plot of f[t] to find an initial value for t in FindRoot

```
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, .1}]
```

[image]

```
Clear[a]

a = a /. FindRoot[
    NIntegrate[f[t], {t, 0, a}] == 1, {a, 0.08}] //
  Quiet
```

> 0.0680318

Check

```
NIntegrate[f[t], {t, 0, a}]
```

> 1.

```
Show[
 RegionPlot[0 <= t <= a && y <= f[t],
  {t, 0, .1}, {y, 0, 40},
  PlotPoints -> 50,
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio],
 Plot[f[t], {t, 0, .1}]]
```

[image]