# How to add a condition to a formula so that it will not appear at the result?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

Sometimes I have very long and complicated equations, when I evaulate the equations for example taking derivative or integral there will be several conditions with the answer.
My question is that; is there any way that I enter the conditions at the begining of the program so that so that it will not appear in the evaluation result?

I will give a simple example:

```
pdf = x^(L-1)/( γ^L Gamma[L]) Exp[(-x)/γ];
Re[L] > 0;

Integrate[ pdf, {x, 0, γ}]
```

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[ (Gamma[L]-Gamma[L,1])/(Gamma[L]),  Re[L] > 0 ]
> ```

in the above example even if I write the condition which is `Re[L] > 0`, it will appear again at the result of evaluation.

Comment: Most likely you are looking for ways of imposing assumptions. This question is closely related: [How to specify assumptions before evaluation?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/how-to-specify-assumptions-before-evaluation) or simply a duplicate.

Comment: thanks for the answers.
my question is is specifically that; is there anyway to write conditions at the begining of the program so that you don't need every time repeat them with your equations.

Comment: Have you read answers to the linked question? Namely you need `$Assumptions = Re[L] > 0` and appropriately writing your integral.

Comment: Hi Artes,
that was the answer of my question.
`$Assumptions = Re[L] > 0`

you can write all your conditions at the begining of the program like this:

`$Assumptions = Re[b] > 0 && Re[Sqrt[b]] > 0;`

by putting  `&&` between your conditions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `Assuming`, eg. for your particular example:

```
Assuming[{Re[L] > 0}, 
 Integrate[x^(L - 1)/(\[Gamma]^L Gamma[L]) Exp[(-x)/\[Gamma]], {x, 0, \[Gamma]}]]
```

This gives:

> `1 - Gamma[L, 1]/Gamma[L]`

Answer (score 3):

```
cdf = Integrate[pdf, {x, 0, \[Gamma]}, GenerateConditions -> False]
```