# Am I missing something in this integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to solve this simple integral:

```
Integrate[Cos[m*x]*Cos[mp*x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 Assumptions ->  
  Element[m - mp, Integers] && Element[m + mp, Integers] && 
   m - mp != 0 && m + mp != 0]
```

which is zero. However, Mathematica gives:

```
1/2 (Sin[2 (m - mp) \[Pi]]/(m - mp) + Sin[2 (m + mp) \[Pi]]/(m + mp))
```

Why?, any tip?

Thanks

Comment: The result is correct, to see it is just `0` you need `Simplify[%, (m | mp)  ∈  Integers]`, or `Assuming` or `$Assumptions` etc. Take a look at closely related post: [How to specify assumptions before evaluation?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/how-to-specify-assumptions-before-evaluation/2406#2406)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Assuming[(Element[m - mp, Integers] && Element[m + mp, Integers] && 
   m - mp != 0 && m + mp != 0), 
 Integrate[Cos[m*x]*Cos[mp*x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]]
```

yields 0. It seems that functions of the parameters in assumptions are not interpreted,