# FullSimplify used with Assuming giving unexpected results

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

Can someone shed some light on why

```
Assuming[{x ∈ Reals}, x (Sign[x]^2 - 1)] // FullSimplify
```

returns

```
x (-1 + Sign[x]^2)
```

instead of zero please?
I know one can not expect `FullSimplify` to perform miracles but this example does seem pretty obvious.

Comment: It returns zero for me. Version 9.0.

Comment: `FullSimplify[x (Sign[x]^2 - 1), Assumptions -> {x \[Element] Reals}]` gives 0 on version 9.0.1

Comment: ver@cormullion, I have a 64 bit 9.0.1.0 student version on a 64 bit Win 8 machine and get what I posted.

Comment: Sorry @cormuullion, I posted my comment too quickly. Yes I also get zero for your modified example using Assumptions, but the question still remains for my original example.

Comment: @Anon, you get zero? Are you using a student version?

Comment: @Freakalien Yes, and I'm using the student version as well. But I'm using ver. 9.0.0.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example evaluates

```
Assuming[{x ∈ Reals}, x (Sign[x]^2 - 1)]
```

BEFORE simplifying.

The correct way to inform your assumptions to `FullSimplify[]` is:

```
FullSimplify[x (Sign[x]^2 - 1), Assumptions -> {x ∈ Reals}]
```

Which returns zero.

Or

```
Assuming[{x ∈ Reals}, FullSimplify[x (Sign[x]^2 - 1)]]
```

Comment: Yep, makes sense. Cheers...

Answer (score 6):

**1.** The first reason is that `Sign[0]` yields `0`, so even assuming `x ∈ Reals` this expression:
 `Sign[x]^2 - 1` cannot be evaluated to `0`.

**2.** The next problem is that `Assuming[{x ∈ Reals}, x (Sign[x]^2 - 1)]` is evaluated first, then the assumption imposed doesn't affect the simplification procedure since `FullSimplify` being outside `Assuming` doesn't know anything about `x`, thus the final result is correct.

**Ad 1.** In general `Sign` is a complex function, for a complex number $ z\neq0\;$ it is equal to `z/Abs[z]`, e.g. see its graphs of the real and imaginary parts:

```
GraphicsRow[ Table[ Plot3D[ f @ Sign[x + I y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
                            ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors",], {f, {Re, Im}}]]
```

[image]

**Ad.2**

One can impose global assumptions for a *Mathematica* session, e.g.

```
$Assumptions = z ∈ Reals;
```

then one can do as it was assumed in the question:

```
z (Sign[z]^2 - 1) // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

On the other hand you can use assumption restricted to `FullSimplify` only:

```
FullSimplify[ x (Sign[x]^2 - 1), x ∈ Reals]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

For more detailed discussion see e.g. this question [How to specify assumptions before evaluation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/how-to-specify-assumptions-before-evaluation).

Comment: I don't have the points to up vote your answer so thanks.