# Excluding an interval of parameters from Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'd like to compute an integral that depends on a parameter, but I'd like to exclude an interval from the computation.  For concreteness, say I want to compute

```
Integrate[f[x,z],{x,-a,a}]
```

but I would like to specify that z is a complex number *not* in the real interval [-a,a].  Any thoughts?  If I let the integral run, I get a conditional expression that I think is correct, but I'd like to specify the exclusion ahead of time if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: `z<-a || a<z` is the way to express this if `z` is real.  Do you only want to exclude this interval for reals, but not for any `z` value where `Im[z] != 0`?

Comment: The answer to your question  can be found (if you read it carefully) e.g. here: [How to specify assumptions before evaluation?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/how-to-specify-assumptions-before-evaluation).

Comment: @Artes That answers it - thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Using the suggestions found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/how-to-specify-assumptions-before-evaluation), I was able to use

```
Assuming[If[Element[z,Reals],(z<-b||z>b)]&&b>0,Integrate[f[x,z],{x,-b,b}]]
```

Comment: I don't think this syntax is correct for assumptions. You can't use `If` this way (or rather: Mathematica won't interpret it the way you think it would.)

Comment: It seems to work. (i.e. it gives me the same answer as my calculation by-hand, and with no conditional expressions)