# Telling mathematica that something is an integer

Tags: variable-definitions

Is it possible for me to tell mathematica something is an integer?

like if I typed

```
Sin[n Pi]+Cos[n Pi]
```

it would tell me it equals 1 for even n and -1 for odd n?

This would really help me check my answers when trying to find Fourier Series (I am just learning them now)

Comment: Try: `Assuming[Element[n, Integers], Simplify[Cos[n Pi] + Sin[n Pi]]]` OR `Simplify[Cos[n Pi] + Sin[n Pi], Element[n, Integers]]`

Comment: Use e.g. `Simplify[Sin[n Pi] + Cos[n Pi], n ∈ Integers]`. More details can be found here [How to specify assumptions before evaluation?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/how-to-specify-assumptions-before-evaluation).

Comment: @Artes, I'm curious, how is what you wrote different from my second suggestion?

Comment: @RunnyKine There's a good link.

Comment: @Artes, okay :)